# Fill values from Active Directory to array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, active-directory

My code is defined as follows:

```
Dim objGroups As Object
Dim arrMemberDN As Variant
Dim arrList() As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set objGroups = GetObject("LDAP://" & strGroupDN)

For Each arrMemberDN In objGroups.member
    arrMemberDN = Mid(arrMemberDN, 4, 7)
    arrList(i) = arrMemberDN
    i = i + 1
Next arrMemberDN
```

But I always get the

> runtime error 9: Index out of range

on `arrList(i) = arrMemberDN`

How can I fill my array `arrList` with value from `arrMemberDN`?

Comment: You need to set dimensions for your array. E.g. `redim`

Comment: That is because you have not set a size for the arrList array it only has one spot.  You need to redim the array to the size of the objGroups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you have to create dimensions for your array, here it is for a 1D array.

Then you `Redim Preserve` to keep the content that you had in it.

**NOTE : `Redim Preserve` can only be use to alter the LAST dimension!**

```
Dim objGroups As Object
Dim arrMemberDN As Variant
Dim arrList() As Variant
ReDim arrList(1 To 1)


Set objGroups = GetObject("LDAP://" & strGroupDN)

For Each arrMemberDN In objGroups.member
    arrMemberDN = Mid(arrMemberDN, 4, 7)
    arrList(UBound(arrList)) = arrMemberDN
    ReDim Preserve arrList(LBound(arrList) To UBound(arrList) + 1)
Next arrMemberDN
ReDim Preserve arrList(LBound(arrList) To UBound(arrList) - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to @R3uK's suggestion. You were close, if you can get a count of the objects in `objGroups` before you start your loop you can set the limits of `arrList` just once, which will be quicker.

```
Dim objGroups As Object
Dim arrMemberDN As Variant
Dim arrList() As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set objGroups = GetObject("LDAP://" & strGroupDN)
ReDim arrList(1 to 'count of items in objGroups)

For Each arrMemberDN In objGroups.member
    i = i + 1        
    arrMemberDN = Mid(arrMemberDN, 4, 7)
    arrList(i) = arrMemberDN
Next arrMemberDN
```

Comment: How do you count an object variable with values by AD?

Comment: Well, you used `objGroups.member` to get members, perhaps `objeGroups.member.count` would count them?

Comment: No, It doesn't. I get an error that this method isn't defined.

Comment: Okay, do you know how to debug? Place a breakpoint on the `For Each...` line. And open your Locals view. You should find your objGroups object. Expand it and look for any property that is counting the objects. It might not exist, but it also might!